# Why is my multiline text file coming out as 1 line with std::getline?

Tags: c++

```
int main() {
    std::ifstream infile("/Users/CRYPT3X/desktop/c++ Practice/sample.txt");
    if (!infile.fail()) {
        std::string str;
        std::getline(infile, str);
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my code. The issue is that I have 2 different files with the same contents:

```
0,8,6,0,5,0,3,0,0
4,0,7,0,9,0,0,0,0
5,2,0,8,7,0,0,0,0
0,5,0,0,8,0,0,0,0
7,1,0,0,4,0,0,6,5
0,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,0
0,0,0,0,1,8,0,4,3
0,0,0,0,6,0,1,0,9
0,0,5,0,3,0,8,7,0
```

This is sample.txt. This one I typed by hand into textEdit and the code prints out just the top line like you would expect.

```
0,8,6,0,5,0,3,0,0
4,0,7,0,9,0,0,0,0
5,2,0,8,7,0,0,0,0
0,5,0,0,8,0,0,0,0
7,1,0,0,4,0,0,6,5
0,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,0
0,0,0,0,1,8,0,4,3
0,0,0,0,6,0,1,0,9
0,0,5,0,3,0,8,7,0
```

This is sample2.txt. I had originally created this one in excel as a csv file and then converted it to a txt file while trying to debug this problem. When I copy and paste the contents of both files into new, different files. I get the same results. the copy and pasted file of sample.txt prints out 1 line like I would expect, but when I copy and paste sample2 into a different file, the entire contents is printed out. Please tell me what is going on here? Thanks

Comment: Was one of the files created on another operating system, by chance? You could try opening both of them in an editor that can show special characters and check the line endings - `\r`, `\n` or `\r\n` - probably they were saved with different settings, one of which matches your system's settings that `getline` uses.

Comment: just tried creating another csv file in excel and it printed out the whole thing again. If I want the code to work with any csv file then how are you supposed to know if it is going to be all one line or not?

Comment: I just read that on mac, the end of a csv file line is \r instead of \n

Comment: http://nicercode.github.io/blog/2013-04-30-excel-and-line-endings/

Comment: i guess that kinda explains it a bit. seems to be a problem with excel but super frustrating

Comment: change `std::getline(infile, str);` -> `std::getline(infile, str, '\r');`, if success, you got answer.

Comment: On the *old* Mac operating system (before OSX) then yes the newlines were `'\r'`, but since OSX is based on UNIX the newlines since its introduction is `'\n'`.

Comment: yeah if you read that article above, in excel, saving it as windows csv uses \n, but the regular excel csv saves it with \r